# tizen emulator not running on debian

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

I failed to run Tizen Emulator on debian 8 with intel processor, i'm using Tizen Studio 1.2.
I don't get any error messages on window alert and logs file, I tried to delete and re-create the emulator but it not work.

thanks in advance

**Update :** i'm getting error messages from logs on vms

```html
08:25:02.331| 9158|I|      main| 345|Start emulator...
qemu args: =========================================
"/home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64" "-drive" "file=/home/edi/tizen-studio-data/emulator/vms/m-0730-1/emulimg-m-0730-1.x86,if=none,index=0,cache.no-flush=on,id=drive" "-device" "virtio-blk-pci,drive=drive" "-drive" "file=/home/edi/tizen-studio-data/emulator/vms/m-0730-1/swap-m-0730-1.img,if=none,index=1,id=swap" "-device" "virtio-blk-pci,drive=swap" "-enable-kvm" "-device" "vigs,backend=gl,wsi=vigs_wsi" "-device" "yagl,wsi=vigs_wsi,protocol=23" "-smp" "4" "-m" "512" "-device" "virtio-maru-sensor-pci,sensors=accel&geo&gyro&light&proxi&haptic&uv&press&hrm" "-device" "maru-camera,index=0" "-device" "virtio-maru-nfc-pci" "-netdev" "user,id=net0" "-device" "virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0" "-chardev" "file,path=/home/edi/tizen-studio-data/emulator/vms/m-0730-1/logs/emulator.klog,id=con0" "-device" "isa-serial,chardev=con0" "-device" "virtio-serial" "-L" "/home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/data/bios" "-kernel" "/home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/data/kernel/bzImage.x86" "-append" "vm_name=m-0730-1 video=LVDS-1:720x1280-32@60 dpi=295  host_ip=10.0.2.2 console=ttyS0" "-display" "maru_qt,rendering=onscreen,resolution=720x1280,dpi=295" "-device" "virtio-maru-touchscreen-pci,max_point=10" "-device" "AC97" "-device" "virtio-maru-esm-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-hwkey-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-evdi-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-keyboard-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-vmodem-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-power-pci" "-device" "codec-pci" "-device" "maru-brightness" "-nodefaults" "-rtc" "base=utc" "-M" "maru-x86-machine" "-usb" "-vga" "none" "-device" "virtio-maru-jack-pci,jacks=earjack&charger&usb" 
====================================================
08:25:02.331| 9158|I|      main| 348|qemu main start...
08:25:02.333| 9158|I|emul_state| 690|initial display resolution: 720x1280
08:25:02.333| 9158|I|qt5_consol| 171|display density: 295
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
08:25:02.337| 9158|S| backtrace| 191|Got signal: 6(Aborted)
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 182|Backtrace depth is 18
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0000 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(+0x52db7b) [0x556ce4a58b7b]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0001 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(+0x52dc71) [0x556ce4a58c71]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0002 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890) [0x7f3af1504890]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0003 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x7f3af117f067]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0004 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f3af1180448]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0005 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZNK14QMessageLogger5fatalEPKcz+0xcf) [0x7f3af28f446f]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0006 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Gui.so.5(+0xfd81c) [0x7f3af30a081c]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0007 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Gui.so.5(_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate21createEventDispatcherEv+0x2d) [0x7f3af30a089d]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0008 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN16QCoreApplication4initEv+0xaa5) [0x7f3af2af1725]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0009 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN16QCoreApplicationC1ER23QCoreApplicationPrivate+0x25) [0x7f3af2af18f5]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0010 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Gui.so.5(_ZN15QGuiApplicationC1ER22QGuiApplicationPrivate+0x9) [0x7f3af30a4949]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0011 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/libQt5Widgets.so.5(_ZN12QApplicationC2ERiPPci+0x52) [0x7f3af38d4962]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0012 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(qt5_early_prepare+0x126) [0x556ce49fabf6]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0013 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(maru_early_qt5_display_init+0x20) [0x556ce49fa520]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0014 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(qemu_main+0x4b7a) [0x556ce4a787fa]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0015 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(main+0x264) [0x556ce482b594]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f3af116bb45]
08:25:02.340| 9158|I| backtrace| 184|#0017 /home/edi/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.4/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64(+0x303f21) [0x556ce482ef21]
Aborted
```

Comment: I have a similar issue on Windows 10. Mine is complaining about the tuner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem I've done by myself

after getting error messages with logs file on vms, i'm trying to fix some part, i'm just do

creates the symbolic link.

`sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/`

for reference please visit this link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without
and the emulator can run with normal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYcKV.png)